# Magento2: Production Critical Error on Cloudinary

Tags: magento2, image, php-7, fatal-error

I am trying to run the `setup:upgrade` command I get the following error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   getCloud() on null in
>   /var/www/asprod/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary-magento2/Model/Configuration.php:149
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /var/www/asprod/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary-magento2/Core/ConfigurationBuilder.php(20):
>   Cloudinary\Cloudinary\Model\Configuration->getCloud()
>       #1 /var/www/asprod/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary-magento2/Model/BatchDownloader.php(156):
>   Cloudinary\Cloudinary\Core\ConfigurationBuilder->build()
>       #2 /var/www/asprod/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary-magento2/Model/BatchDownloader.php(150):
>   Cloudinary\Cloudinary\Model\BatchDownloader->_authorise()
>       #3 /var/www/asprod/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Cloudinary\Cloudinary\Model\BatchDownloader->__construct(Object(Cloudinary\Cloudinary\Model\Configuration),
>   Object(Cloudinary\Cloudinary\Core\ConfigurationBuilder),
>   Object(Cloudinary\Cloudinary\Model\MigrationTask),
>   Object(Cloudinary\Api),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\ in
>   /var/www/asprod/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary-magento2/Model/Configuration.php
>   on line 149

I am using these steps to install **cloudinary**

```
composer require cloudinary/cloudinary-magento2 
php bin/magento maintenance:enable 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento maintenance:disable 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Using **PHP 7.0**, **Magento 2.2.0** and Ubuntu 18.04.
Without the cloudinary extension, everything is working fine but the site doesn't display any images since they are all hosted on Cloudinary.

Comment: Can you put up to code for /var/www/asprod/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary-magento2/Model/Configuration.php maybe lines between 100 and 200. But the problem is there.

Comment: The code can be found here https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_magento2/blob/master/Model/Configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

getEnvironmentVariable() is returning null.

Either your credentials are being rejected or encrypted values that have previously been saved are not being interpreted.

Check your credentials. If correct raise with extension developer.